# how to pass hash reference to a subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm stuck on a problem. I'm trying to make references for 2 hashes, then compare them in a subroutine. However, there is an error:

Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at compareHashes.pl line 10.

My code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $hash_1; my $hash_2;
compareHashes($hash_1, $hash_2);

sub compareHashes{
    say "the first hash:", "\n", %$hash_1;
    say "the second hash:", "\n", %$hash_2;
    if ((keys(%$hash_1) eq keys(%$hash_2)) and (values(%$hash_1) eq values(%$hash_2))){
        say "Two above hashes are equal";}
    else {
        say "Two above hashes are not equal";
    }
};

my %hash1 = (ITALY => "ROME",
        FRANCE => "PARIS"
        );
my %hash2 = ( ITALY => "MILAN",
        FRANCE => "PARIS"
        );
my %hash3 = (ITALY => "ROME" );
my %hash4 = (SPAIN => "ROME",
        FRANCE => "PARIS"
        );
my $hash1_r = \%hash1;
my $hash2_r = \%hash2;
my $hash3_r = \%hash3;
my $hash4_r = \%hash4;

compareHashes ($hash1_r, $hash1_r);
compareHashes ($hash1_r, $hash2_r);
compareHashes ($hash1_r, $hash3_r);
compareHashes ($hash1_r, $hash4_r);
```

Please tell me what is wrong. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You didn't assign any value at all to $hash_1 or $hash_2, so they are undefined?

Comment: maybe i define say. try to use print.

Comment: yes. I'm trying to compare 4 "real" hashes.

Comment: Your code is a mess. Your function ignores its arguments, you are using uninitialized lexical variables in the file scope, which gives the error message. Your comparison of keys with `eq` only compares how many keys each hash has.

Comment: You can't compare a list of strings using a single operator; you need a loop. You will also need to use `sort` so that the elements of the two hashes are in the same order. Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never assigned to `$hash_1` and `$hash_2`!

```
my ($hash_1, $hash_2) = @_;
```

---

You have more problems than that, however, both `keys` and `values` in scalar context return the number of elements in a hash, so you are simply checking if both hashes are of the same size!

```
sub are_hashes_equal {
    my ($hash1, $hash2) = @_;

    {
        my %set;
        ++$set{$_} for keys(%$hash1);
        --$set{$_} for keys(%$hash2);
        return 0 if grep { $_ } values(%set);
    }

    for my $key (keys(%$hash1)) {
        return 0 if $hash1->{$key} ne $hash2->{$key};
    }

    return 1;
}
```